# Node/Gulp synchronous deletion of directory within task

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, build, gulp, synchronous

I have a task like this:

```
gulp.task('test', function(){

  del('./build');

  gulp.src('./test/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));

});
```

Essentially, this is supposed to first DELETE the `build` directory, and then it is supposed to copy a bunch of files to a new `build` directory.

My question: Are these two commands asynchronous or synchronous? It is obviously important that `del` runs and finishes before files are copied to a new version of that same directory.

If they are async, then how do I make them run synchrnously? Is my only option to break them out into individual tasks and have the `del` task a dependency to the "copy task"? Is there no way to make streams synchronous within a single task?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to delete the directory synchronously, you can just use `fs` directly:

```
var fs = require('fs');

gulp.task('test', function(){

  fs.rmdirSync('./build');

  return gulp.src('./test/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));

});
```

Comment: I assume the `Sync` implies that method runs synchronously?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `del()` asynchronously, you can do it like this:

```
del('./build', function(err) {
  gulp.src('./test/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that function `del.sync` works:

```
del.sync('./build');
```

[documentation of "del" package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del)